# 1990s end of the world book

Tags: identification-request

I read this book in the 90s about the end of the world relating to a comet or asteroid hitting the earth. First chapter was in an observatory I think and next chapter in the desert? Not much to go on but this was almost 30 years Ago! I’d love to read it again!

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please read the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] your question to add further details. For example, what language was this in? Where were you geographically located? What context did you acquire the book in (school, library, etc.)? How large was it, both in terms of cover area and thickness? What age range was it aimed at? Do you remember any illustrations - cover image, chapter images, even?

Comment: @Sara M. Young ,understandably the 90's are 3 decades ago but  as Bobble opines additional info would ease the burden of searching. Details helpful in I.Ding the book in additon to the above are info re the books as a physical object thick, thin , cover art what was shown , and idosyncracies , Authorial details : one or more authors , illustrations , Publisher, original language of publication / translation ,date of publication ( you read it in the 90's )  Audience ( eg YA , Adults ) , tie ins movies , games , plot details ( as you have provided ) begining, twists & ending .Sequels , series  .

Comment: Two thoughts with the info so far are :1.  Lucifers Hammer 1977 but multiple reissues including one in the 90's ,by  Larry Niven & Jerry Pournelle .Early chapters have an amateur astronomer and a boy called Brown  visualizing an asteroid .2. The Hammer of God : Arthur C Clarke 1992 .

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t remember any other details or I would have shared already :( I borrowed the book from a friend when we were in junior high. No other details… I really appreciate your suggestions for me! I will pursue those!